# Two meteor instances connected to one database - delay issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nginx, meteor

I have two big parts of the application. Main part that works on domain.com and another one on admin.domain.com. Both are connected to one database, because I need the same data for both of them.

domain.com - localhost:3001 and admin.domain.com - localhost:3002 .   Nginx in front for reverse proxy.

Everything works fine, but when data is changing by admin.domain.com  application, I have a big delay while this data is updating on domain.com

As I understand, I need to enable mongo oplog?  Is that right? And how to do this?

upd: Also I don't have such a long delay when two users connected to one meteor instance, in that case meteor reactivity works fine, and data updates for two users very quickly. I mean, the problem is in the frequency with which meteor polls database about any changes.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because Meteor is pulling the database each 10 seconds, with OPLOG this is almost instant. Even with OPLOG you can experience slow updates because you depend on the Mongoldb cpu in some scenarios such as aggregations.

If you're using pass the URL to the Mongodb OOLOG server:

`export MONGO_OPLOG_URL=mongodb://localhost:$MONGO_PORT/local`

Comment: Is that all what is needed to turn on oplog? Should I need to reload mongo or meteor instances?

Comment: Yes, you need to set this has an environment variable and Meteor will use the oplog. So you've to restart your servers.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post on setting up [oplog tailing and Meteor](http://projectricochet.com/blog/magic-meteor-oplog-tailing).  I think it will answer your question.  It won't cut down on the roundtrip client -> server and server -> client times, but I don't suspect that's where your delay is anyways.